# Flash AS3 Looping Gallery

Tags: actionscript

How to make the gallery looping.when last image in the gallery finished i want to show from the beginning.(horizontal auto scrolling the images from right to left).Please help!

Here the code below for scrolling but i want to scroll continuously when last image over

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftSideScrolling);

private function leftSideScrolling(e) {

```
 galleryWidth = rootClip.imageContainer.width;
 speed = -(0.02 * (980 - 620));
```

rootClip.imageContainer.x+=-2;

```
  if (rootClip.imageContainer.x>0)
{

  rootClip.imageContainer.x= (-galleryWidth/2);

}
```

if (rootClip.imageContainer.x<(-galleryWidth/2))
 {

```
rootClip.imageContainer.x=0;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scrolling the container, scroll the images inside the container.Assuming you're scrolling from right to left, when an image x is inferior to its width , meaning that the image is out of view , add it to the end of the image container, which would be the total width of the container minus the width of the image you're moving. that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have progressive loading if you have many images in order to load certain amount at the time, but if you wish to go with what you have, then throw a loading flash movie when loading an image, limit loading amount of images, once user start to scroll, hide off screen images and load next x amount of images. As PatrickS mentioned, scroll images (flash movie clips) instead of container. All images should be located under a movie_clip to apply effects, all movie clips should be located under container to have scrollbars and move positions with AS1/2/3.